# How to show data by using KEY, KEYREF in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have "library". There are books and books' categories.
I just want to know how can I display book's category which are connected with book by ID.

The result will be a table of all books and their categories.

It is in Czech language but I think you will understand it.

knihovna = library, kniha = book, kategorie = category, nazev = name

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='knihovna.xsl'?>
<knihovna

        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="knihovna.xsd"
>
<knihy>
        <kniha id_kniha="k-1">
            <nazev>Válka s mloky</nazev>
            <kategorie>kat-1</kategorie>
        </kniha>
        <kniha id_kniha="k-2">
            <nazev>Povídky z druhé kapsy</nazev>
            <kategorie>kat-2</kategorie>
        </kniha>
        <kniha id_kniha="k-3">
            <nazev>Obsluhoval jsem anglického krále</nazev>
            <kategorie>kat-1</kategorie>
        </kniha>
        <kniha id_kniha="k-4">
            <nazev>Báječná léta pod psa</nazev>
            <kategorie>kat-1</kategorie>
        </kniha>
        <kniha id_kniha="k-5">
            <nazev>Svatý Xaverius</nazev>
            <kategorie>kat-3</kategorie>
        </kniha>
</knihy>
<kategorie>
        <kategorie_knihy id_kategorie="kat-1">
            <nazev>Romaneto</nazev>
        <kategorie_knihy id_kategorie="kat-2">
            <nazev>Román</nazev>
        </kategorie_knihy>
        <kategorie_knihy id_kategorie="kat-3">
            <nazev>Povídka</nazev>
        </kategorie_knihy>
        <kategorie_knihy id_kategorie="kat-4">
            <nazev>Alegorie</nazev>
        </kategorie_knihy>
    </kategorie>
</knihovna>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <xs:element name='knihovna'>  
    <xs:complexType>  
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name='knihy'>  
          <xs:complexType>  
            <xs:sequence>  
              <xs:element name='kniha' type='knihaVzor' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />  
            </xs:sequence>  
          </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>  
        <xs:element name='kategorie'>  
          <xs:complexType>  
            <xs:sequence>  
              <xs:element name='kategorie_knihy' type='kategorieVzor' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />  
            </xs:sequence>  
          </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>   
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>      
    </xs:element> 

<xs:complexType name="knihaVzor">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nazev" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="kategorie" type="xs:string"/>               
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id_kniha" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="kategorieVzor">
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="nazev" type="xs:string"/>                
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="id_kategorie" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSL:

```
     <table width="100%" border="1">
        <th>Nazev</th>
        <th>Rok vydani</th>
        <th>Pocet stran</th>
          <xsl:for-each select="knihovna/knihy/kniha">    
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="nazev" />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="rok_vydani" />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="pocet_stran" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>              
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="knihovna/kategorie/kategorie_knihy[@id_kategorie='WHAT HERE?']">   
                      <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="nazev" />
                      </td>
          </xsl:for-each>  
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="categories" match="kategorie_knihy" use="@id_kategorie" />
```

(The name can actually be anything here!)

Then, to use it in your `xsl:for-each` do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('categories', kategorie)">   
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="nazev" />
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Although this `xsl:for-each` would need to be nested in the previous one on the `kniha` elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="categories" match="kategorie_knihy" use="@id_kategorie" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <th>Nazev</th>
      <th>Rok vydani</th>
      <th>Pocet stran</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="knihovna/knihy/kniha">    
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="nazev" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="rok_vydani" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="pocet_stran" />
            </td>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('categories', kategorie)">   
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="nazev" />
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>  
          </tr>              
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, if a book can only have one category, you wouldn't need the `xsl:for-each` here at all. You could just do this...

```
<td>
  <xsl:value-of select="pocet_stran" />
</td>
<td>
  <xsl:value-of select="key('categories', kategorie)/nazev" />
</td>
```

Comment: It is working, thank you a lot. Can you explain me, what the definition of key are exactly doing? Because I dont see the connection between <kategorie> in element "kniha" and id_kategorie in element "kategorie_knihy"

Comment: There's probably not enough space in comments to explain about how `xsl:key` works. Try reading up on them at https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html though, for example. Thanks!